# How do I down grade my react navigation in a current react-native project?

Tags: react-native

I started a new react-native project and have already finished the backend and added to github. When I came to the front end and started installing react-navigation and it's dependencies I started running into a ton of issues, after resolving most I am not at the point where I don't have any errors but nothing is displaying on my expo screen. I tried to resolve but got the error saying I needed to upgrade expo. My computer is a bit older and I don't have enough space to upgrade it's software so I am unable to upgrade expo. This is just a personal project, I would like to go ahead and downgrade react navigation from v5 to v4 because I know the v4 dependencies work with my version of expo. How would I go about doing this? Do I need to delete my package json, package json lock and node modules and npm install, and install all react navigation again?

My package json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^3.8.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "expo": "^37.0.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.15.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am not sure if I need to include anything else for help with this issue...

these are the current errors I am now getting:
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:

- react-native-gesture-handler - expected version range: ~1.6.0 - actual version installed: ^1.8.0
- react-native-maps - expected version range: 0.26.1 - actual version installed: 0.27.1
- react-native-reanimated - expected version range: ~1.7.0 - actual version installed: ^2.1.0
- react-native-screens - expected version range: ~2.2.0 - actual version installed: ^2.15.2
- react-native-safe-area-context - expected version range: 0.7.3 - actual version installed: ^3.1.9
- @react-native-community/masked-view - expected version range: 0.1.6 - actual version installed: ^0.1.10
  Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.

jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
Error: Watchman error: root was cancelled. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.

I have tried to rerun watchman with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete your `package.json`! A simple way to do it would be to uninstall the current `react-navigation` dependencies you have by running `npm uninstall react-navigation`. That should remove it from your `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

Then, you can re-install it while specifying the version you want, for example `npm install --save react-navigation@4.x.y`. I'm not sure which exact version you'll need, so you can replace the `x` and `y` to whatever version you need.

You can do that with basically any dependencies, so you can make sure they are all compatible together by specifying the version you want to install.

Answer (score 1):

No need to delete package.json.
run following command

npm uninstall --save @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/bottom-tabs @react-navigation/stack

this will uninstall react-navigation 5 and its features.

for installing and working with react-navigation 4  follow official doc.

here is the link for react-navigationv4 doc
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/getting-started/