# Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version

Tags: react-native, package, expo

Hello I am learning `expo` for react Native and while running my app i get the error below. My app runs fine but i just want to get rid of the error.
is there something like   `npm update` i can do to get rid of this error

here is the error:

Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:

- @react-native-picker/picker - expected version: 2.4.0 - actual version installed: 2.4.2
- react-native-safe-area-context - expected version: 4.2.4 - actual version installed: 4.3.1
- react-native-screens - expected version: ~3.11.1 - actual version installed: 3.13.1
  Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
  To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo doctor --fix-dependencies,
  or install individual packages by running expo install [package-name ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually this does the trick

```
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```

2024 update:

```
npx expo install --check
```

-prompts you about packages that are installed incorrectly. It also prompts about installing these packages to their compatible versions locally.
You can also use :

```
npx expo install --fix
```

read more https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/

Comment: FYI as of 2024 the command for this is `npx expo install --check`. `npx expo-doctor` just tells you there are issues without fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that the expected version of some of your installed libraries are lower than the actual versions that you installed. You need to downgrade your dependencies to match the expected version to get rid of the warnings.

First you will need to uninstall the above packages by the command: `npm uninstall [library-name]`. For example: `npm uninstall react-native-screens`

After that, you will need to reinstall the above libraries using their recommended version: `mpn install react-native-screens@3.11.1`

You can also refer to this for more information: [How do I down grade my react navigation in a current react-native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67096039/how-do-i-down-grade-my-react-navigation-in-a-current-react-native-project)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your package:

- npx/npm install "example/package@newversion".
  and in your case you need to update like this:
- npx expo install @react-native-picker/picker@2.4.8